# What is the meaning of the word 'veritical'?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word

What is the meaning of the word 'veritical'?

I've heard intellectuals use this word, it seems to mean *truth*, like it's derived from veritas- but I can't find it anywhere. Maybe I'm not spelling it correctly. Is anyone familiar with it?

Comment: This seems like a guessing game since you're not sure what it means and you're not sure of the spelling.

Comment: The word is: **veridical**. It means truthful.  I can see why you got it wrong. :)

Comment: @Lambie - I turned your comment into a CW; feel free to add your own answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, although there is nothing wrong with its being asked, OP now has an answer (provided by Lambie in a comment) and it is very unlikely to be of interest to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

[@Lambie](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/100179/lambie) wrote in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/607625/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-veritical#comment1534743_607625):

> The word is: **veridical**. It means truthful. I can see why you got it wrong. :)

[(See Merriam-Webster's definition for the word)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veridical)

Comment: I have no problem with  your doing that. :) I am not a scrooge. But I fear we're going to be booted.

Comment: @Lambie - ??? Do you mean the close votes?

Comment: I sure do. What a pity. I thought it might be a good example - totally understandable - of t's and d's being muddled.

Comment: I approve of the 'answer without using a normal "answer" ', but agree with the CV-ers  that the question is unsuitable for ELU in the first place. ELU doesn't have a suitable vehicle for helping enquirers without encouraging unsuitable questions.

Comment: The "philosophical argument" above at least highlights that all of the words, let alone their spellings, are another product of the theatre of the mind.  And, as such, then what to make of philosophy, itself, either?  Or, can all of that, and more, spring from some level of space-time beneath our own?

Comment: And, yes, I enjoyed this one.  Shame to delete, delete, and delete.

Comment: The word is probably related to *veritas,* the motto of Harvard College.

Answer (score 1):

The word that the OP has heard is, indeed, as Lambie has already said, *veri**d**ical*, rather than *veritical*.

In philosophical terminology, where its 'home' is, the meaning of that word is close to that of *true*, but not quite the same. The need for having such a word has arisen because philosophers tend to be very strict in treating truth and falsity as the properties of propositions. One can thus, in that standard philosophical terminology, say that the proposition *The snow is white* is true, and that the proposition *The snow is green* is false, but one cannot say that the visual sensation of whiteness that one has when one’s eyes are directed at the snow is true, nor that the sensation of greenness under the same circumstances (that somebody might have because of some visual illusion) would be false, because sensations are not propositions. The person who has such sensations can report them in propositions, but the sensations are distinct from the propositions in which they are reported, and that limits which adjectives can be used to characterise them.

So, if the philosophers' terminology precludes them from saying that, say, sensations, are true, how do they express the obvious quality that the sensation of whiteness when looking at the snow has, and the sensation of greenness under the same circumstances lacks? The solution was to bring the word *veridical* in, and say that the sensation of whiteness when looking at the snow is veridical.

In everyday communication, most people do not feel constrained to limit their use of *true* in the way in which its is limited in philosophical contexts. Because of that there is rarely any need to use *veridical* outside philosophical contexts.

Comment: More like the sensation of color is true, but, snow isn't white.  "Despite the extraordinary experience of color perception, all colors are mere illusions, in the sense that, although naive people normally think that objects appear colored because they are colored, this belief is mistaken. Neither objects nor lights are colored, but colors are the result of neural processes."